# IOS fullscreen video player crash issue

Tags: ios, video, crash, avplayer

When I was debugging the iOS application, meet with some issue causing application to crash when playing video in fullscreen mode and this issue is concerned with the specific device `iPhone 6s`. The application works good in `iPhone 6` and `iPhone 5s` without crash.

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-09-12 17:41:50.50 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-09-12 17:41:27.27 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.4 (13G35)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000180a96234
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a96234 CFEqual + 512
1   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000182025a3c CGGradientCreateWithColors + 232
2   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000182025a3c CGGradientCreateWithColors + 232
3   UIKit                           0x000000018621cf34 +[UIProgressView _tintedImageForHeight:andColors:roundingRectCorners:] + 356
4   UIKit                           0x0000000186109524 __50-[UISlider _updateMaxTrackColorForInitialization:]_block_invoke + 148
5   UIKit                           0x00000001860217b0 +[UIView _performSystemAppearanceModifications:] + 68
6   UIKit                           0x000000018610942c -[UISlider _updateMaxTrackColorForInitialization:] + 476
7   UIKit                           0x0000000185f74c08 -[UISlider _initImages] + 568
8   UIKit                           0x0000000185f7495c -[UISlider layoutSubviews] + 92
9   MediaPlayer                     0x0000000189ad0544 -[MPVolumeSlider layoutSubviews] + 56
10  UIKit                           0x0000000185d141e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001836a698c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001836a15c8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
13  UIKit                           0x0000000185d2b0a4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 924
14  UIKit                           0x0000000185d30bec -[UISlider setValue:animated:] + 184
15  MediaPlayer                     0x0000000189ad0c8c -[MPVolumeSlider volumeController:volumeValueDidChange:] + 84
16  MediaPlayer                     0x0000000189b68074 __39-[MPVolumeController updateVolumeValue]_block_invoke_2 + 240
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001806054bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018060547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018060ab84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b70d50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b6ebb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a98c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
23  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182380088 GSEventRunModal + 180
24  UIKit                           0x0000000185d82088 UIApplicationMain + 204
```

Comment: show your code in question!

Comment: We use the  Cordova Webview to play video in fullscreen mode.